# Not able to get more pages in paginatedoutput on swift

Tags: swift, amazon-dynamodb

I need help!
I am trying to read out my DynamoDB to an IOS app in Swift.
Seems that the SDK only scan with PaginatedOutput.
I am not able to get paginatedoutput to load more pages. Lastevaluatedkey is aways the same and no more pages get loaded.
Here is my code:
    ---

```
    func scan(){

    let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    scanExpression.limit = 5000
    let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
    dynamoDBObjectMapper.objectMapperConfiguration.consistentRead = 0
    dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(Rplaces.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask!) -> Any? in
        self.paginatedOutput = task.result
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            print("next " , self.paginatedOutput?.lastEvaluatedKey ?? "")
            for item in self.paginatedOutput?.items as! [Rplaces] {
                print("place ", item.id ?? 0)

            }

        })

        if self.paginatedOutput?.lastEvaluatedKey != nil{
            print("second loop " , self.paginatedOutput?.lastEvaluatedKey ?? "")
            self.loadMoreResults()
        }
        return true
    })

    return
}

func loadMoreResults() {

    paginatedOutput?.loadNextPage(completionHandler: {(error: NSError?) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            print("next " , self.paginatedOutput?.lastEvaluatedKey ?? "")
            for item in self.paginatedOutput?.items as! [Rplaces] {
                print("place ", item.id ?? 0)

            }

        })
        } as? (Error?) -> Void)
}
```

}